# Why are my basement walls half finished?

Tags: walls, cement, basement-refinishing

Our below grade basement has cement walls that look like they are half completed? How would we finish the walls so it’s fully smooth.. what is the purpose why it was built like this? [image]

Comment: What's on the other side?

Comment: Maybe it was intended to have wainscoting originally so they didn't finish the bottom half the same as the top?

Comment: Depending on your location it may it may be likely to have leaks closer to the bottom as Gnico mentioned so wainscoting would cover this, but it can be finished with a similar cement based product , if painted an acid etch would help both adhesion and sealing. I have used an add mix to improve sealing qualities but sealing from the inside can be a lost cause if a high water table.

Comment: It looks like the surface finish was damaged by water. it probably still leaks.

Comment: This is normal in much of the US.

Comment: This is an interior wall, not adjacent to an outdoor wall. Not possible for leaks. Past or present.

Comment: @Jasen If it was from water I think it would be stained.  It doesn't look like it is.

Answer (score 2):

The top is parged, the bottom is not. Why is a question you'd have to ask the people that built it, and they are long gone. Parge the rest of  it.

Parging is applying mortar or plaster with a trowel to make a smooth surface. The lower part of the wall still has the impressions of the form boards (and they were boards, not plywood, so it's presumably old.)

Alternatively, apply thinset and tile it.